# I can not show a specific div

Tags: jquery

I am beginner with jquery and I have a problem, I can not access the div `edicionDieta`

This is my code

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dia a").click(function () {
    $(".sombraAlimentos").show();
    $(this).find(".edicionDieta").show("slow");
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="sombra alimento"></div>
<div id="dia">
    <a>Cambiar</a>
    <div class="edicionDieta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This site uses English. Please translate.



Comment: to reference an ID in jQuery, use `$('#dia a')`, the dot `.` is to reference classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="sombra alimento">
    sombra alimento content
</div>
<div id="dia">
    <a>Cambiar</a>
    <div class="edicionDieta">
        edicionDieta content
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dia a").click(function () {      
    $(".sombra.alimento").show();
    $(this).parent().find(".edicionDieta").show('slow');
  });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nXjH/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="sombraAlimentos"></div>
<div id="dia">
    <a>Cambiar</a>
    <div class="edicionDieta"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dia a").click(function () {
    $(".sombraAlimentos").show();
    $(this).next(".edicionDieta").show("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  find `id` components using `#` and `class` using .
```

HTML

```
<div class="sombra alimento"></div>
<div id="dia">
    <a>Cambiar</a>
    <div class="edicionDieta" style="display:none">a</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
  $("#dia a").click(function () {
    $(".edicionDieta").show("slow");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaVM7/

Answer (score 0):

Your error is using the class selector on a div. Update your code as following:

```
...
$("#dia a").click(function () {
...
```

Also, in your markup:

```
<div class="sombra alimento"></div>
```

looks incorrect. You probably want to change it as such:

```
<div class="sombraAlimento"></div>
```

Comment: And also OP is looking for a descendant inside the `<a></a>`? Did you notice that.?

Comment: you're right, I didn't notice that. thanks for pointing it out, yours is a more complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dia a").click(function () {
    $(".sombra.alimentos").show();
    $(this).parent().find(".edicionDieta").show("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is wrong - in your HTML it is `sombra alimento` and in your JS it is `sombraAlimentos`.

Also, in your JS you are using `.dia`, but your HTML is using `id="dia"`.

To fix this, change your HTML to:

```
<div class="sombraAlimentos"></div>
<div class="dia">
    <a>Cambiar</a>
    <div class="edicionDieta"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#dia a` instead of `.dia a`

```
 $("#dia a").click(function () {
     $(".sombra.alimento").show();
     $(this).parent().find(".edicionDieta").show('slow');
 });
```

Comment: watch out, Your selector is wrong, you are looking for a descendant inside an anchor tag.